# Running a git command from vscode extension

Tags: javascript, vscode-extensions

I am new to VSCode extension.
I have created a basic extension. Now I want to update the extension so that it will execute a git command (lets say 'git status') when I run my extension.
Can someone please guide me?

Below is my code snippet. Now it just **shows some messages**. Instead of showing message, I want to run/execute some system or any kind of command here.

```js
function activate(context) {
    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('helloworld.myCommand', function () {
        
    // The code you place here will be executed every time your command is executed

        // Display a message box to the user
        
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Hello World from HelloWorld!');
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you provide information on what you have so far? And where exactly you want to add that step?

Comment: Well , as off now, I have a basic vscode extension where I am showing some messages with vscode.window.showinformationMessage(). The code is in extension.js. Now instead of showing the message, I want to run some command from here. Thank you..

Comment: Please edit your question and post your current code if possible. Otherwise share a reproducable example so that others have a better chance to understand your problem and your goals

Comment: You may also want to check how to add syntax highlighting to your code here https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help :-)

Comment: Thank You for the edit and the link !!